# SQL Server sp_msforeachtable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sp-msforeachtable

I am having a problem with using the `sp_msforeachtable` SQL Server stored procedure.

I want to have output of `EXECUTE` statement in one table using following SQL query:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE DaneOSpuscie --clear the table

EXEC sp_msforeachtable 
    'INSERT INTO [DaneOSpuscie] ([Database name], [Table name])
     SELECT  ''?'', name
     FROM [sys].[columns] 
     WHERE [sys].[columns].[name] LIKE ''%[Tt][aA][pP12]%'' '
```

This throws an error

> String or binary data would be truncated

for each table.

Additional info: Table "DaneOSpuscie" has only two columns: Database name, Table name of type varchar.

Comment: The error message suggests that one or both of the columns of the `DaneOSpuscie` table is too narrow. Use the `sysname` datatype for both columns.

Comment: This worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your table structure.
Check your max length of your objects.

Compare it. Set your columns in your table to real max length or use maximal system object length - `sysname = nvarchar(128)`.